# GWT 2D Drawing with canvas

Tags: java, gwt

i need a drawing service on client side with X & Y axis and grid. I tried com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas but even with one rectangle painted on it it loads several seconds on local web server. 
Did you face performance issues with that library? Or any suggestion which library/widget to use to provide user drawing on scaled grid?

Comment: It takes about 5 seconds to see the rectangle painted. Canvas size 450 x 800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, you run in development mode which isn't very fast to start (Did you use it?). In order to make it load faster, you should compile it to JavaScript and then load the page.